# How can I determine the size of historical apt-get updates?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, file-transfer

I'm trying to understand how much raw data one of my Ubuntu 18.x boxes consumes due to updates.  Is there a log that can tell me?  I see that there's package names in /var/log/dpkg.log but I don't see a summary of the historical download sizes for each upgrade operation.

Comment: I think you would need to write an update script that tracked this information.

Comment: Option 2 is to use an `apt-cacher-ng` server so you will not only use less bandwidth with repeated updates but have a more complete statistics of how much data you use - https://read-me.su/apt-cacher-ng-kesher-deb-paketov-iz-repozitoriya/ - Yes, that page is not in english. Just take a look at the "statistics" print...